# ADFS Implementation for Internal Applications

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, wif, saml-2.0, adfs

We are looking forward to implement ADFS to implement SSO across our organization for various set of web applications such as (SAP, Siebel, Custom java based, Asp.net etc.).
I understand based on my research that ADFS can be used to achieve SSO for third party applications using SAML. It can act as an identity provider for third party applications. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can we use the ADFS to implement cookie based SSO for the various internal web based apps which I mentioned above?? (For Ex: CA Siteminder, ORacle Access manager can work with almost every internal web based application)

In other words: we have one application using apache webserver, one using IIS webserver, one using IHS webserver; can ADFS be used to achieve Single sign on with all these applications??? If yes, How ???

Thanks in Advance...!!

Ashish

Answer (score 1):

ADFS implements SSO via federation using either WS-Fed or SAML 2.0.

If these applications can support these protocols, then yes just federate these products with ADFS and you will get SSO.

e.g. [SalesForce SSO with ADFS](http://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/).

For Java you need a SAML stack e.g. Spring Security.

For ASP.NET, use OWIN or WIF.